# Macro-Excel Sheet crashes when opening

Tags: vba, excel

Okay, I did something to my sheet and I went to test it, and it crashed.  Well, I figured, whatever, it's fine.  But the problem is, the code runs from the workbook open code.  Is there any way possible to remove the code from the workbook open sub without having the project open?

I know one can enter the file by changing the extension to .zip.

Comment: [disable macros in the Trust Center](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-documents-HA010031071.aspx) using another workbook, then open your workbook without enabling macros and delete code from `workbook_open` event

Comment: I also had to use this one when I inadvertantly moved the problem line of code to an area that runs on open but not in the workbook open sub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing the LHS Shift key while opening the workbook should supress the `Workbook_Open` code.

Comment: This one worked, thanks.